# Why does entity framework not set the foreign key fields when assigning a property

Tags: entity-framework

So, I have a few classes that are stored in my database and they have things on them, here is a small sample of a class:

```
public class Order {

    //Stuff

    [ForeignKey("QuoteIdField")]
    public virtual Quote Quote { get; set; }

    [Column("QuoteId")]
    public virtual Guid? QuoteIdField { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Guid QuoteId {
        get { return QuoteIdField.HasValue ? QuoteIdField.Value : Guid.Empty; }
        set { QuoteIdField = value; }
    }

    //More stuff...
}
```

When I wrote this quick unit test method to check my Entity Framework integration, I found that the quote ID wasn't being set.

```
using (var db = new DataContext()) {
    var order = new Order();

    //order.Quote is null
    //order.QuoteIdField is null

    order.Quote = db.Quotes.FirstOrDefault();

    //order.Quote is not null
    //order.QuoteIdField is null

    db.Orders.Add(order);
}
```

Have I misunderstood something about EF? Does it not set the foreign key when you assign a property?

Comment: Check it out **after** `db.Orders.Add(order);` line.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh yeah. Is there a way to get it to do that to all the properties before I add it? (without assigning them directly)

Comment: AFAIK, unfortunately no.